# Firebase not removing eventlistener using 'gdx-fireapp'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, libgdx

I'm trying to implement Firebase in a LibGdx app using [gdx-fireapp](https://github.com/mk-5/gdx-fireapp) library.
I can read, change or remove any data successfully, but when I try to remove an event listener after getting the data that I want it does not get removed. I'm supposed to call `cancel();` for this to happen, but nothing happens. I've even tried calling  `cancel();` multiple times but it still doesn't work. is anyone familiar with how can I fix this?

Here is how I call it

```
        GdxFIRDatabase.inst()
                .inReference("Rooms/")
                .onDataChange(Map.class)
                .then(new Consumer<Map>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Map map) {
                        Gdx.app.log("test","onDataChangedCalled");
                    }
                });
```

And here is how I cancel it:

```
        GdxFIRDatabase.inst().inReference("Rooms/").onDataChange(Map.class).cancel();
```

After `cancel();` is called it is supposed on stopping logging "onDataChangedCalled" when the value changes
but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that faces the same problem, you have to store the listener to a variable and use this variable to call it and cancel it.

Here is how I did it:

```
    ListenerPromise<Map> Rooms;

        Rooms = GdxFIRDatabase.inst().inReference("Rooms/").onDataChange(Map.class);

        GdxFIRDatabase.promise()
                .then(Rooms)
                .then(new Consumer<Map>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Map map) {
                        Gdx.app.log("test","onDataChangedCalled");
                    }
                });
```

and to cancel it just call `cancel();` like this:

```
Rooms.cancel();
```